# How to access files in custom directory created on root in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel

I need to access files in a directory created at root of laravel 5.4.
Have not been able to get file contents in custom directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `base_path()` method that Laravel gives you. This is the root of your Laravel application. You pass the folder and file names as an argument:

```
base_path('folder-name/file-name.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ProjectName/Directory_name/../your_file.php");
```